# Как вывести список ролей участника сервера?

Tags: python, бот, discord

Нужно вывести список ролей участника в discord.Embed, бот их выводит, но выглядит это вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[...]

Роли выводятся строкой `ctx.message.author.roles`
Как сделать вывод ролей упоминанием?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Учитесь пользоваться документацией. Там все описано, и можно полный путь понять, что возвращает каждый из вызовов. В данном случае `roles` возвращает List[Role]. [Описание](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Role) класса `Role`. К каждому атрибуту можно обратиться.
Как пример:

```
result = [(role.id, role.name) for role in ctx.message.author.roles]
```